# C# Is holding data in a delimited string bad practice

Tags: c#

Is it bad practice to have a string like 
"name=Gina;postion= HouseMatriarch;id=1234" to hold state data in an application.I know that I could just as well have a struct , class or hashtable to hold this info.

Is it acceptable practice to hold delimited key/value pairs in a database field– just for use in where the data type is not known at design time.

Thanks...I am just trying to insure that I maintain good design practices

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, holding your data in a string like "name=Gina;postion= HouseMatriarch;id=1234" is very bad practice. This data structure should be stored in structs or objects, because it is hard to access, validate and process the data in a string. It will take you much more time to write the code to parse your string to get at your data than just using the language structures of C#.

I would also advise against storing key/value pairs in database fields if the other option is just adding columns for those fields. If you don't know the type of your data at design time, you are probably not doing the design right. How will you be able to build an application when you don't know  what data types your fields will have to hold? Or perhaps you should elaborate on the context of the application to make the intent clearer. It is not all black and white :-)

Comment: And he has a big problem storing the name of the guy called “Robert’); Drop table students,–”... because than he has one field to much...

Comment: And think about what would happen if you had a comma in your data - the format would break down!

Answer (score 3):

Well, if your application only passes this data between other systems, I don't see any problems in treating it as a string. However, if you need to use the data, I would definitely introduce the necessary types to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

Well one immediate problem with that approach is embedded escape chars. Given your example what would happen if the user entered their name as follows:

Pet;er

or

Pe=;ter

or

pe;Name=Yeoi;

I am not sure what state data it is you are trying to hold, and without any context it's hard to make valid suggestions. Perhaps a first step would be to replace this with a key value pair, at least that negates the problem mentioned above and means you don't have to parse strings regularly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will find your application easier to maintain if you make a struct or class to hold the data and then add a custom property to return (and set) the string you been using. This method will take the fields and format it in the string that you are already using and do the reverse (take the string and fill the fields) This way you maintain maximum compatibility with your old algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

I try to not keep data in any string based formats. But I encountered several situations, in which it was not possible to know in advance how the structure of the data will be (e.g. it was possible for the customer/end-user to dynamically add fields).

In contrast to your approach, we decided to store the data in XML, e.g. in your case this would be something similar like this:

```
<user id="1234">
 <name>Gina</name>
 <postion>HouseMatriarch</position>
</user>
```

This gives you the following advantages:

- The classes to work with the data (read/write) are already available in the framework (e.g. XmlDocument or XML serialization)
- you can easily exchange the data with other systems (if/when required)
- You can store the data in a file
- you can store the data in a database column (xml data type). You can even query that column when using SQL Server (although I'd try to avoid storing data in XML, that has to be queried)
- using XML allows to add additional fields to your data at any time

**Update**: I'm not sure why my answer was downvoted that much - maybe it is because of the bad example. Therefore I'd like to make it clear: I would not use XML for properties such as an ID/primary key of a user, or for standard properties like "name", "email", etc. But for "extended/dynamic" properties (as described above) I still think this is an easy and elegant solution.

Comment: +1 This should not have been downvoted.  This is XML serialization!!

Comment: This is one of the best answers on the page - whomever is downvoting ought to comment on their reason.  Martin is describing XML serialzation which is an excellent way of storing an object in string form.

Comment: Of course, this approach shouldn't be used everywhere. It is always better to have a well designed domain model. But as I described, IMO there are situations where it can be very useful.

Comment: One of the worst development experiences I've had in my entire career was the result of inheriting a design that stored XML in a relational database.  XML has its uses, but for storage and manipulation of data, it can be a nightmare.

Comment: If XML isn't good for storage and manipulation of data then what is it good for?

Comment: There is no technique that cannot be "a nightmare" if it's employed by someone who doesn't understand good practices and why they exist.

Comment: Using XML for data interchange and storage is feasible, but it is also the essentially most expensive way that this can possibly be done; there are cheaper and easier alternatives.  We should be opting for XML as a LAST resort, not the FIRST one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store structured data in a string I think you should use a standard notation such as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice because of the amount of effort you have to go to, to construct the strings and parse them later.  There are other more robust ways of serialising data for passing between systems.

For core business data, suitably designed classes will be far simpler to maintain, and with all the properties strongly typed, you'll know early on when you mis-type a property name.

As for key-value pairs, I'd say they're sometimes Ok, sometimes not.  If there are a lot of possible values, but not a lot of actually owned values, then it can be perfectly all right to use KVPs.  Sebastian Dietz's alternative of having a separate column for each field would result in a lot of empty fields in that case.  It would also mean extra work altering the table every time you needed a new one.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers has mentioned normalization yet, so I thought I would.  When database fields are involved, one of the key principles of normalization is that each field in a table only represents one thing.  Delimited fields violate that principle.

One of the guys at Red Gate Software posted [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/) along those lines that you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well it just means that it is less searchable or indexable as a hashtable would be. It would also require a bit of processing to get into a state where it could be easily used by other bits of code. For example a bit of code that queries the id in that data would be something horrible such as:

```
if(dataStringThing.Substring(26, 4) == SomeIdInStringFormat)
```

So yes in most cases it is bad practice. However in other cases where this might be a default format that you need to retain the data in or performance means that you only should parse it as and when required. So it may not be a bad thing.

I would suggest myself if you have reasons to keep it in that format that it might be best to transform it into a class that separates the fields but also create a ToString() implementation on that class that restores it to the original format if you also need this. If the performance of it is a concern then modify this object to only parse the source into the fields in the class the first time those fields are accessed.

To re-iterate nothing in isolation is necessarily a bad practise. Bad practises are context dependant.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion to wrap the string in a parser class: wouldn't the additional overhead justify the simplified implementation of a struct or class with separate properties? In theory, the string would be a private member anyway. (cont'd)

Comment: Individual member access would be faster and more reliable with properties that accessed individual private properties with backing fields; and if he wanted the full string, an overridden ToString() implementation would do the job handily on the few occasions he needed it.

Answer (score 0):

It (hopefully) obviously shouldn't be a normal choice. But there are cases where it's useful or necessary.

I can't think of any cases that wouldn't involve it being part of a communications protocol with some external service (e.g. a database connection string), so you're probably stuck with the format.

If you have a choice in the format (perhaps you are writing both sides of a system which can only communicate using strings), then at least choose something structured and well known. Examples of such have been given elsewhere, but the prime ones are naturally going to be XML or JSON. CSV, or some other delimited format may be useful in very simple cases (such as the database connection string) - but pay special attention to escaping delimiter characters (as the "Bobby Tables" joke (already referenced in another comment) nicely illustrated - google for him if you are not familiar with that one).

Your mention of a database suggests that this may be where the focus is. Are you trying to serialise application objects? (there are other ways of doing that). As another poster said, this may be a sign of a design that needs rethinking. But if you do need to store unknown datatypes in a DB, then XML may be an appropriate choice - especially if your DB supports XML fields. It's a bit of a minefield, though, so make sure you are familiar with how they work first.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not that bad when you are using a StringList for manging your string. 
Especially when the structure of a e.g configuration-string (or configuration-database field) must be flexibel.
But in normally you should not do this, because of this disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you need a heirarcical format of data or lots of fields that preserve data type, then no... a parsed string is a bad idea.

However, if you just need to transmit a string across a service and byte-conservation is important, then a Tag-Data pair may be exactly what you need.

If you do use a parsed string, it's important to be able to get at the data inside and quickly manage it. If you want an example TDP class, I posted one today to my website:

http://www.jerryandcheryl.net/jspot/2009/01/tag-data-pairs.html

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest considering these usage factors.

If you are processing the data within your own code, then you can use whatever data structures you wish.  However, you may have issues developing your own implementation of a complex data structure, so consider using a pre-built one instead.  Many come with whatever programming platform you may be using, while many more are documented in various books, articles, and discussions both printed and online.  If you properly isolate your work from others, then you can safely do whatever you want.

On the other hand, if you need to share that data with others, then most careful consideration should be given.  If you must share the data with an API, or via a storage mechanism (database, file, etc.), or via some transport (sockets, HTTP, etc.), then you should be thinking of others first and foremost.  If you wish success and respect from your efforts, then you need to pay attention to standards and conventions and cost.  Thankfully, practically any such use that you can imagine has been done before, so you can leverage others' efforts.

In a database, consider how others (and yourself) will be inserting, updating, deleting, and selecting the data.  For example, using XML in a database makes all these steps unnecessarily hard and expensive compared to the alternatives.  Pay attention to database normalization--learn it if you are not familiar already.

If you are dealing with text, pay attention to character encodings and make them explicit.

If there is an existing standard or convention for what you are doing, honor it.  If there is a compelling reason to deviate, then accept the burden of justifying it, explaining it, and making it easy for others to accommodate your choices.

If you control both sides of a communication/transport medium, feel free to optimize.  If you don't, err on the side of interoperability.  Remember that a primary difference between the two scenarios is the level of self-description embedded with the data:  interoperability has lots, optimization drops it based on shared assumptions.  Text-rich data is more understandable, but binary is faster.

Think about your audience.